# about a fundamental domain and its volume

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, volume

Let $a, b, c$, pairwise coprime squarefree integers.

Suppose $au^2 + bv^2 + cw^2 ≡ 0 (mod\ 4)$ with $au^2 , bv^2 , cw^2$  pairwise coprime and $(u, v, w) ⊂ \Bbb Z^3$

Let $Λ_0 := \{(x, y, z) ⊂ \Bbb Z^3 : aux + bvy + cwz ≡ 0 (mod\ |abc|)\}$

Let $Λ := \{(x, y, z) ∈ Λ_0 : y ≡ x (mod\ 2) , z ≡ 0 (mod\ 2)\}$.

Prove that if $2 \nmid abc$ and $2|w$ then fundamental domain for $Λ$ has volume $4|abc|$

It is clear that in the fundamental domain we can take: $0<z<2$ and $x<y<x+2$, but how to find an interval for $x$ in order to compute the volume? my intuition is that $0<x<|abc|$ but how to proceed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I wouldn't do this by trying to find a fundamental domain. I'd do this by proving the index of the subgroup $\Lambda$ in $\Bbb Z^3$ is $4|abc|$.

Comment: Thank you @Lord Shark. I see why it's an additive subgroup by how to find the index? I can't see the cardinalities of $Λ_0$ and $Λ$. Could you please detail the relationship between the index of $Λ$ and its volume?

Comment: If $\Lambda_1\supseteq\Lambda_2$ with $|\Lambda_1:\Lambda_2|=k$ then the volume of $\Lambda_2$ is $k$ times that of $\Lambda_1$. Indeed one can build a fundamental domain of $\Lambda_2$ from $k$ translates of one of $\Lambda_1$.